# how to save in column mode (block mode) in vim

Tags: vim, save

I want to save a block of a file in vim into another file. I can enter the block mode by Ctrl-V, and select the block. But I do not know how to save the selected text into another file.

For example, the original file is as follows:

```
123Jane
456Amy
Happy new Year
```

And I want to save into a new file the following text:

```
123
456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is copy and paste the block into another file.

- select block-wise with `<c-v>`
- yank the selected text via `y`
- open file via `:e` or `:sp`. e.g. `:sp foo.txt`
- put/paste the register via `p` or `:put`
- save the file via `:w`

Answer (score 1):

there is no built-in method for that, but you can give this function a try:

```
function! Save_visual_text(filename)
  try
    let v_save = @v
    normal! gv"vy
    let txt = @v
    let lines = split(txt, '\n')
    call writefile(lines, a:filename)
  finally
    let @v = v_save
  endtry
endfunction
```

if it works for you, you can wrap it in a command, or create mapping etc. to make it easy to call.